# How to track multiple conversions on separate pages for one Facebook ad?

Tags: javascript, facebook, analytics, facebook-ads-api, web-analytics

I am trying to setup a FB ad campaign so we can track multiple events from each ad to test effectiveness. I've spent over 2 hours talking to FB support, one member of staff told me this is absolutely not possible, the other told me that it was possible with the new Custom Audience Pixel (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/v2.4).

We have 4 separate signup forms on our site and i want to track how many of each type of signup are generated from each ad.

This can't be done using the standard pixel as you can only associate one pixel/event with one ad.

So if i use the new custom audience pixel and install it on all pages of the site then i can setup a CompletedRegistration using:

```
fbq('track', 'CompleteRegistration', {
content_name: 'Signup1',
status: 1,
value: 1,
currency: 'GBP'
});
```

But i was told you can only have one of each event type so we couldn't use this separately for each form (although i'm not 100% sure whether that's correct). Does anyone know if i can use the above and then create another CompletedRegistration event with content_name=Signup2 and then be able to track both of these separately within Ad Manager?

If not then in theory i can setup custom events like the following:

```
fbq('trackCustom', 'Signup1', {
value: 0,
currency: 'GBP'
});
```

and create multiple ones of these (for 'Signup2/Signup3' etc) and include each on a different signup page. Which would hopefully allow me to track each event individually within ad manager and see the total conversions for each event for each ad.

Can anyone confirm which is the correct way to do it as Facebook staff don't seem to know how it works (as i was told by them!) and without knowing the restrictions it's impossible to test without setting it all up and then paying for ads!

Thanks everyone,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the content_name for standard events to match the associated form, yes. If all forms are on the same page you should set up your site to fire the FB pixel event on form submit so you don't accidentally fire on the forms the user did not submit. You can also fire a custom event for the form submit, yes.

The relevant FB documentation page on custom audience pixels is at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/v2.4 and you can use the stats edge to read the event names and data reported https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-website-pixel-stats/v2.4

Comment: Thanks very much bjeavons. The forms are all on separate pages. So to confirm I can setup 4 standard conpletedregistration events as shown above with different names (one for each form) and track all of them separately for one ad in ad manager? Thanks!

Comment: That's right. I'm doing similar with same standard event of 'Purchase' and different content_id.